# Form in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

Views:

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in posts.post">
    {{x.name}}  {{x._id}} {{x.post}} {{x.user_id}} 
    <br>
    <form>
        <textarea  ng-model='new_comment.comment' name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
        </textarea> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Post Comment!" ng-click="addComment(x._id)" >
    </form>
</ul>
```

Here's the controller:

```
$scope.addComment = function(id) {
    postFactory.addComment(id, $scope.new_comment, function () {
        postFactory.getComment(function (data) {
            $scope.comments = data;
        });
        $scope.new_comment = {};
    });
};
```

Here's the factory:

```
factory.addComment = function(id, info, callback) {
    console.log(info);
    $http.post("/saveComment/" + id , info).success(function() {
        comments.push({name: info.name, age: info.description, category: info.category});
        callback(comments);
    });
};
```

I have these codes here. The form is not outputting anything in my controller/factory when it's wrapped inside the ng-repeat tag, but when I remove it, it outputs what I want. But I need to access the loop's id (x._id).

Comment: do u see any errors on the console ? , also show JavaScript code

Comment: says undefined when i try console.log(info); in the factory

Comment: Have you declared `$scope.new_comment.comment` somewhere ?

Comment: create fiddle/snippet and add whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller can't access the `new_comment.comment` because `ng-repeat` creates it's own scope. If you define it in the controller all your comment input fields will have a binding to the same model.

The easiest solution is to pass the comment value with the function.

```
addComment (x.id, new_comment.comment)
```

Comment: Had to modify it a little but addComment (x.id, new_comment) works.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using  `<form>` tag

try `<div ng-form="your_form_name">`

Answer (score 0):

**You should try like this**

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in posts.post">
    {{x.name}}  {{x._id}} {{x.post}} {{x.user_id}} 
    <br>
    <textarea ng-form="form" ng-model='new_comment.comment' name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Post Comment!" ng-click="addComment(x._id)" >
</ul>
```

Comment: Tried that. Still outputting 'undefined'. Do I have to do anything with ng-form='form' in the controller/factory?

Answer (score 0):

You must not be declaring `$scope.new_comment`.
Try this:

```
$scope.new_comment = {}; //right after your controller starts.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use of li to wrap your all html and apply ng-repeat on li instead of ul.